# Removing "printf" change program behaviour

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I'm a beginner in c and pointers, but nor with others programming languages.
Something really strange happen with a part of my code:

```
for (int x = minX; x <= maxX; x++){
    for (int y = minY; y <= maxY; y++){
//double loop that list pixels in an area
//p is a Struct that have two variable: x and y (both doubles)
      p.x = (double) x;
      p.y = (double) y;
      
      if (IsPointInTri(&p, &v1, &v2, &v3)){
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x, y);
      }
//when uncommenting these lines, the "if" statement above is called
      //printf("%f  ", p.x);
      //printf("%f\n", p.y);
    }
  }
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

When I remove/comment the two printf, the if condition is always considered as false( the `SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x, y);` is never called). As long they are here there is no problem.

I red other questions so:

1. moving printf (before the if for example) doesn't make an error appear.
2. I'm not using malloc or that kind of things.

Do you know an explanation to this behavior ?

I can provide full code, or explain more if necessary. I'm using gcc9 and ubuntu 20.04.

Full code can be found here : (comments are in french...) https://github.com/ArtemisPlayer/Madfihr

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Your problem is most likely in some other part of the code. This behavior frequently happens when memory is corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! What does that mean ? What can corrupt memory ?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Working on that.

Comment: C has the concept of "undefined behavior", when you do something that has no guaranteed deterministic result by the language. Meaning most of the time a bug. This can in turn screw up completely unrelated parts of the code, due to memory corruption, incorrect code generation and so on.

Comment: Rather than only describe or refer to code, post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is your problem or not, but it would affect how `IsPointInTri()` works. `b1, b2, b3 = 0;` doesn't do what you want. In particular, it's the same as `b1, b2, (b3 = 0);`, not `(b1, b2, b3 = 0);` which would be an error anyway. The comma operator discards the values on the left-hand side(s), you're looking for `b1 = b2 = b3;` instead. Enable compiler warnings and it'll say something like this:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘IsPointInTri’:
foo.c:12:5: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   b1, b2, b3 = 0;
     ^
foo.c:12:9: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   b1, b2, b3 = 0;
         ^
```

With `-O2` or `-O3`, Gcc would also say that `b1` and `b2` are used uninitialized later when you sum `b1+b2+b3`.

Also, `#include "ecran.c"` -- don't do this. There are better ways to compile multiple C files into the same program, including them together loses all encapsulation benefits. Moving all the declarations to proper headers and making a two-line Makefile that compiles all the `.c` files to one program does have some up-front cost, but it's way better. Or just put all the code in one file if you can't bother to do that yet, you only have a few hundred lines anyway.

Comment: Indeed, b1 and b2 were not set to 0 (in facts their value was almost random). Thank you for looking "deep" in the code !

Comment: @ArtemisPlayer, yes, in practice they'd get whatever values happened to be in memory at the time. Calling `printf` could well change that, since it would use the same areas in stack for whatever local variables it needs.